# Loop through HTML element : getting more iteration than expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am using google web app to create a web user form. I have 10 drop down lists (select elements) in a table.

I have a code which loop through all the "select" HTML elements (At the moment I am debugging using only 2 of them) once a button is clicked. I am getting a very weird error, which I do not understand at all. The loop should be through 2 elements, but somehow the code end up looping through 8 elements. 6 of them do not exist!

#### Extracted HTML

select elements (id = pn1, id = pn2):

```html
<tr>
  <td style="font-family: Verdana; width: 300px; text-align: center;height:30px">
    <select id="pn1" style="width: 290px; height: 30px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    </select></td>
  <td style="font-family: Verdana; width: 100px; text-align: center;height:30px">
    <input id="in1" style="width: 90px; height: 25px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;text-align: center;" type="number" placeholder="input #" />
  </td>
  <td id="ea1" style="font-family: Verdana; width: 100px; text-align: center;height:30px">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font-family: Verdana; width: 300px; text-align: center;height:30px">
    <select id="pn2" style="width: 290px; height: 30px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;">
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="font-family: Verdana; width: 100px; text-align: center;height:30px">
    <input id="in2" style="width: 90px; height: 25px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;text-align: center;" type="number" placeholder="input #" />
  </td>
  <td id="ea2" style="font-family: Verdana; width: 100px; text-align: center;height:30px"></td>
</tr>
```

#### Script

```js
document.getElementById("butS").addEventListener("click", submit);

function submit() {
  
  //loop the possible list with values
  var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pn]')
  var pnArray = [];
  var qArray = [];
  console.log(selectElements);

  for (var j in selectElements) {

    var select = selectElements.item(j);
    console.log(j);

    var index = select.selectedIndex;
    if (index > -1) {
      var pn = select.options[index].value;
      pnArray.push(pn);
      console.log(select);
      console.log(index);
    }
  }
}
```

I attached the console log. **"SelectElements" is correct**, it has the 2 elements and the length is 2 as shown in the console. The first two j iteration are also correct. J should stop after the 2 iterations, but it continues and I cannot understand why.

[image]

Comment: BTW, I can solve the issue by changing the loop to : for(var j =0;j<selectElements.length;j++). However it is very strange that the code above loop through element that do not exist and would like to understand why

Comment: hard to follow - please fix indentation...  anything inside a tag(html)/brace(javascript)...  where is sel1 and why is it assigned to selectElement*2*?!?

Comment: I removed that part as it was not relevant. Anyway the issue was due to the "for..in" loop which was unexpectedly looping into the properties too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because of using the `for...in` loop on a NodeList.

As you can see in the console you get a NodeList when you use `var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pn]')`

> Don't use for...in or for each...in to enumerate the items in
> NodeLists, since they will also enumerate its length and item
> properties and cause errors if your script assumes it only has to deal
> with element objects. Also, for..in is not guaranteed to visit the
> properties in any particular order.

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: Thanks, I got it. That was the issue. I expanded the node list in the console and found that there were "hidden" item properties. The for..in loop was looping those proprieties too.

Comment: @Filippo Exactly. You can use `forEach` if you don't want to use a normal `for`loop.